# UI Integration test boundaries - nested api calls

Tags: testing, rest, integration-tests, contract

I am developing the UI of an e-commerce. Actually **it is the checkout page only**.
The entrance URL looks like this: 
myEcomerce.com/{orderGuid}
On load The ui takes the orderGuid as parameter to call the API and get the details. In other words, UI call *getOrderDetails* passing the *orderGuid*.

My main concern is in relation with the Testing strategy used to **integrate** UI and API. For an automation test, I will need a valid *orderGuid*.

We already had a discussion between UI and API teams. API offers an extra endpoint to create an Order in order to get a valid {orderGuid}

My integration tests in the ui could be...

1. call *createOrder* (only to get a valid order id)
2. call *getOrder*
3. populate the view
4. asserts..

The UI never will consume this endpoint (*createOrder*) in production, in fact, this endpoint is consumed by other api client....

UI is forced to work in this extra endpoint (*createOrder*) if they want to integrate with API. You could imagine this new extra maintenance effort. 
Deal with the order creation could not be easy.

I believe the API should **provide a "Sandbox" environment and a list of valid {orderGuid}s for multiple testing propose**. Instead of push this complexity to the consumer.

I do not pretend UI deals with the Order creation only for testing propose. Whatever change in this order creation process is going to affect our hundreds tests making them really fragile.
I believe we are not going in the right direction if we need to call the order creation from the UI to retrieve a valid {orderGuid}

Any better idea to deal with the integration tests?

Comment: "the UI never will consume this endpoint in production" then it shouldn't consume it in the tests. I do not understand why you think it needs to.

Comment: "UI is forced to work in this extra endpoint integration if they want to integrate UI with API." looks like a direct contradiction to "the UI never will consume this endpoint in production" to me. Please clarify.

Comment: Let me clarify, UI displays a checkout page, to do that, UI calls _get order_ service from the API sending the orderGuid as a parameter.
API returns the _order details dto_ and UI populates the view.

To recreate this scenarios with an integration test, I should provide a valid _orderGuid_ At this stage is where the UI is forced to "create a valid order" to get a valid _orderGuid_. API exposes _createOrder_ to do that.

@DocBrown the ui never will call the _createOrder_ in production. But if we go in this direction, I should maintain an extra call (_createOrder_) only for testing propose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with your reasoning. If UI never creates an order in production, your UI tests shouldn't be doing it.

Yes, the test environment should be mocked or initialised in a state ready for the UI tests to run.

I see this as a parallel to a use case for, say, testing a user creating a post on a blog - if the UI portion under test is not responsible for creating that user, then it should be given a test environment where a valid user exists and then simply attempt to create a post with that user.

Given this is an integration test, if the API team have built the API such that you cannot test your UI unless a valid order exists, then there needs to be a mechanism to initialise the test environment API such that your code can run on it.

(and that mechanism shouldn't involve re-inventing a whole other section of the UI)

Comment: Could you provide academic resources to support it?

Comment: I don't know of any that cover this case. It's fairly context specific, but the basic principle is you shouldn't be spending time debugging your tests - which means that the setup for the test should be as simple and straight forward as possible. If `POST /orders` is simple enough, then the API team might be able to argue that's the easiest way to get tests going, but if, as you seem to say, it's multi-step and prone to change then there should be an easier way to set up your tests.